# Elasticsearch config folder volume mount into docker compose

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, docker-compose, volume, elk

I have install ELK using docker compose file but due to some error i want to store the logs of Elasticsearch into my logs file  using volume mount.

How can i mount elastic config file into my config file.
How can I get the logs of Elasticsearch into my Log directory

elasticsearch:
image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.9
environment:
- "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
- logger.level=DEBUG
volumes:
- /opt/Service/data/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
- /opt/Service/config: ./bin/elasticsearch
ports:
- 9200:9200
user: ${USER_ID}

How to get Logs of Elasticsearch ?